# Python Term Frequency vectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

With the help of [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) from the Pythons's package scikit-learn, we can easily transform a list of documents into a dataset with features `<term>-frequency-inverse-document-frequency`, where `term`s are the words that appear in the documents.

Is anywhere in Python a TfVectorizer-analogue of the TfidfVectorizer that would produce `<term>-frequency` features, i.e., the values of the features would not we weighted by the inverse document frequency?

I prefer Python solutions over those written in other programming languages, but if you know any easy-to-use implementation in Java, you can also mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's in scikit-learn too and is known as `CountVectorizer`.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

data = ['this is sample 1', 'how about sample two', 'make three samples']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

transformed_data = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)

print (zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), np.ravel(transformed_data.sum(axis=0))))
```

Output:

```
[(u'about', 1),
 (u'how', 1),
 (u'is', 1),
 (u'make', 1),
 (u'sample', 2),
 (u'samples', 1),
 (u'this', 1),
 (u'three', 1),
 (u'two', 1)]
```